# Unreal Engine 5.1.1 crash on Jump

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

My engine keeps on crashing when I jump using `&ACharacter::Jump`.
This doesn’t happen always but it got more frequent recently. Any idea why this is?

I am using UE **5.1.1** compiled from source on Windows.

Here is the trace log:

```
LoginId:508fe6f24e82612fb333a486f622ee7a
EpicAccountId:393905ce12c4434183c7408cb87f2890

Assertion failed: IntFitsIn<OutType>(In) [File:C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Templates\UnrealTemplate.h] [Line: 183] Loss of data caused by narrowing conversion

UnrealEditor_Renderer!FVirtualShadowMapClipmap::FVirtualShadowMapClipmap() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\Renderer\Private\VirtualShadowMaps\VirtualShadowMapClipmap.cpp:173]
UnrealEditor_Renderer!FSceneRenderer::AddViewDependentWholeSceneShadowsForView() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\Renderer\Private\ShadowSetup.cpp:4895]
UnrealEditor_Renderer!FSceneRenderer::BeginInitDynamicShadows() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\Renderer\Private\ShadowSetup.cpp:5767]
UnrealEditor_Renderer!FDeferredShadingSceneRenderer::InitViews() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\Renderer\Private\SceneVisibility.cpp:5195]
UnrealEditor_Renderer!FDeferredShadingSceneRenderer::Render() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\Renderer\Private\DeferredShadingRenderer.cpp:2374]
UnrealEditor_Renderer!RenderViewFamilies_RenderThread() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\Renderer\Private\SceneRendering.cpp:4390]
UnrealEditor_Renderer!<lambda_d825e7d5a738e0bb6b7e834ee381bd9e>::operator()() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\Renderer\Private\SceneRendering.cpp:4668]
UnrealEditor_Renderer!TEnqueueUniqueRenderCommandType<`FRendererModule::BeginRenderingViewFamilies'::`87'::FDrawSceneCommandName,<lambda_d825e7d5a738e0bb6b7e834ee381bd9e> >::DoTask() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\RenderCore\Public\RenderingThread.h:206]
UnrealEditor_Renderer!TGraphTask<TEnqueueUniqueRenderCommandType<`FRendererModule::BeginRenderingViewFamilies'::`87'::FDrawSceneCommandName,<lambda_d825e7d5a738e0bb6b7e834ee381bd9e> > >::ExecuteTask() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Async\TaskGraphInterfaces.h:1348]
UnrealEditor_Core!FNamedTaskThread::ProcessTasksNamedThread() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Async\TaskGraph.cpp:760]
UnrealEditor_Core!FNamedTaskThread::ProcessTasksUntilQuit() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Async\TaskGraph.cpp:649]
UnrealEditor_RenderCore!RenderingThreadMain() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\RenderCore\Private\RenderingThread.cpp:415]
UnrealEditor_RenderCore!FRenderingThread::Run() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\RenderCore\Private\RenderingThread.cpp:541]
UnrealEditor_Core!FRunnableThreadWin::Run() [C:\Users\nikgi\Documents\GitHub Desktop\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Windows\WindowsRunnableThread.cpp:149]
```

This happens randomly when I try to **Jump**.
No **Jump** logic has been overridden and I am using default `CharacterMovementComponent` that comes with **Third Person Template**

Comment: You have a bug somewhere. For a start, study the code around the failed assertion and step through it in a debugger. Check the bugtracker and for updates, too. For a proper question here, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue but it is still strange that this crashes the engine.

Essentially, I was multiplying the `JumpZVelocity` by `Acceleration->GetSafeNormal()` and in some cases it crashes because `CharacterMovementComponent` does not receive any `Velocity` or gets `NaN` in this case which would crash the engine.